# Is it okay to create multiple instances of a device in centos?

Tags: centos, devices

I have a usecase to create multiple char devices of the same type. When I used the same major and minor number of the initially created device, the devices were duplicated and the functionality was maintained.

I wanted to understand if there are any risks, efficiency or performance factors I need to consider while creating devices in this way

Answer (score 0):

The major number identifies the driver to use for that device. The minor number is passed along to the driver, AFAIK other parts of the kernel don't care about it (unless it's for well-known devices where it has a specific meaning).

You didn't include any details about your usecase.

As long as whatever driver you use doesn't need the minor number, my guess is you should be fine. Though the question in this case is why do you need to create multiple devices of the same type in the first place; using a single device would probably work as well.

If you need to reference this device under different names, the convention is to use `udev` rules and make symbolic links.

But to actually answer this we would need information about your usecase, and your reasons for doing so.

Comment: I have a usecase which requires multiple individual devices of the same type. Will these even be considered as different if I use the same major/minor number

Comment: *Why* do you require multiple individual devices of the same type? Which applications are going to use them? What happens if all those application just open the same device? What happens if all those applications open different symlinks to the single device? Who is the entity that needs them to be "different", and which criteria does this entity use? Can you give any background at all, or is it top secret?